# UIProgressView Keeps Resetting to 0.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview, ios9

I've got a UIProgressView in my Storyboard hooked up to my code. I'm trying to set the progress to something non-zero.

Here's an example of my code that I've placed in viewDidLoad.

```
[self.progressBar setProgress:(float)someValueBetween0.1and1.0 animated:NO];
```

However, what's happening is that the progress bar will be at the value that I set, and then quickly animate down to 0.0. For instance, if I set progress to 0.5, the bar will be filled half way when the view loads and then animate down to 0.0.

I've tried using

```
self.progressBar.progress = (float)someValueBetween0.1and1.0;
```

That hasn't worked either.

I'm not modifying the progress bar's progress via code anywhere else. I've tried Googling, reading the UIProgressView Class Reference, and searching Stack Overflow without any success :/

Edit: Created a new project with nothing more than a UIProgressView just to be sure it's not something else in my code. Still not working.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *testProgressView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.testProgressView setProgress:1.0 animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: mate, show the declaration of the progressView and the entire section where you set it

Comment: Created a new project just to be certain that it's not something else in my code messing with the progress bar. This project literally has nothing more than a progress view in an empty view controller. Still the same issue.

Comment: and it's still happening?

Comment: I made a new project, added a progressView in the storyboard, set auto layout constraints to keep it centered. then set the progress like this : [self.progressBar setProgress:0.5 animated:NO];  no issues whatsoever, can you post your project and i'll check it (the new sample one)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gtc4lp9kd6b15w/ProgressViewTest.zip?dl=0 Here's a link to the new project. Using Xcode 7.

Comment: Interestingly, if I set "animated:" to "YES", the progress view does this weird glitchy animation where the size and position of the view changes.

Comment: I'm grabbing Xcode 7 now (beta build 7A120f) to take a look, its really weird, code looks fine! Might be a beta bug, however I'll take a proper look when I have the Xcode beta in a few mins

Comment: Took a quick screen recording of how it looks when "animated:" is "YES" https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xn16tvttlp8wtu/progressViewAnimatedYES.mov?dl=0 As you can see, the progress view's size and position somehow got animated (all while the progress wasn't set to what I specified).

Comment: really interesting... I ran this code in Xcode 6 (had to change deployment target to 8.3 but that was it) and it works perfectly: http://i.imgur.com/u6HaYaO.png .... must be an issue with the beta!

Comment: Wow. That's weird. Guess I'll go report the bug to Apple.

Comment: Yup, good man. When I get the Xcode 7 beta I'll run the test again and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80533/discussion-between-woodstock-and-neil-sardesai).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in Xcode Version 7.0 beta (7A120f).

I've confirmed it in both Objective C and Swift.

It only occurs in the beta version, the same source executes correctly in Xcode 6.

Very strange bug.

Comment: Looks like it's still broken on beta 2.